# Issue with select function in R for Ozone dataset

Tags: r, select, dplyr

I am trying to analyze the Ozone dataset in R but my `select` function is giving an ***error***.

```
library(dplyr
library(mlbench)
data(Ozone)
attach(Ozone)
names(Ozone)
```

which outputs

```
[1] "V1"  "V2"  "V3"  "V4"  "V5"  "V6"  "V7"  "V8" 
 
[9] "V9"  "V10" "V11" "V12" "V13"
```

Then my actual code is:

```
ozone = na.omit(Ozone)
ozone.new = ozone %>% 
  select(-c(V2, V3)) %>% 
  mutate(V1 = as.numeric(V1))
```

The error it gives is

> Error in select(-c(V2, V3)) : unused argument (-c(V2, V3))

I tried running my entire file again which also does not work. I want to remove columns V2 and V3 in the `select()` function and I'm not sure how to fix this?

Comment: I cannot replicate the error (using `dplyr_1.0.2 `)

Comment: Try `dplyr::select(-c(V2, V3))`

Comment: It looks like there is a typo in your call to `library(dplyr)` in example above you are missing the closing parenthases